Difference in total phosphate and total phosphorus of biomass
I'm active in water quality research and have recently had to deal with phosphate measurements. It is not entirely clear to me, however, what exactly is referred to with the various terms in this specific area of research. As I understand there are three things that could be measured: orthophosphate, total phosphate, and total phosphorus. I'm wondering what is exactly the difference between the latter two.
Orthophosphate, I understand, to be $\ce{PO4^3-}$, the simplest form of phosphate that is readily available for biological use by plants and algae. It is an inorganic form of phosphate.
Total phosphate would include condensed phosphates like polyphosphates and organically bound phosphates.
Total phosphorus would include other forms of phosphorus in biomass. But are there forms of phosphorus that aren't phosphates in biomass? In DNA, ATP, or phospholipids, all phosphorus seems to be there as phosphate-groups.
Consulting the analysis protocol from Hach that we are using also uses the terms total phosphate and total phosphorus interchangeably (Hach protocol). Are they essentially the same?
Note: I know that any measurement of phosphate can be expressed both as PO4-P or PO4. This is simply a matter of expression. I am interested in the difference in what is actually measured when someone would take about total phosphate or total phosphorus.

There can be also the variant "total phosphorus as phosphate"

The chemical forms of phosphorus in waterways are very diverse. They can be soluble or particulate, mineral and organic.
Total phosphorus (TP): This is the sum of the contents of all $\ce{P}$-containing compounds present in a water sample, including orthophosphate, phosphorus monoester, phosphorus diester, phosphonate, polyphosphate monoester, polyphosphate, and pyrophosphate (Ref. 1; also read Ref. 2). Although orthophosphate is the most accessible form of $\ce{P}$ for organisms, TP represents the maximum potential amount of bioavailable$\ce{P}$ (Ref. 2)
Total Phosphorus (TP) = Particulate Phosphorus + Dissolved Phosphorus = Mineral Phosphorus + Organic Phosphorus (see here).
Ref. 1 states that:

TP is an important environmental variable that can be used as an indicator of water quality and as a control parameter in waste water treatment processes.

Total phosphates: According to Environmental Water Quality Information, this is a measure of only the phosphate components of phosphorus such as orthophosphate, pyrophosphate, polyphosphate, etc. Thus, it may not included phosphate ethers.
Based on these facts, total phosphorus and total phosphates are not essentially the same things.
References:

Jian Ma, Yuan Yuan, Tingjin Zhou, and Dongxing Yuan, "Determination of total phosphorus in natural waters with a simple neutral digestion method using sodium persulfate," Limnology & Oceanography: Methods 2017, 15(4), 372-380 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1002/lom3.10165).
David M. Karl and Karin M. Björkman, "Chapter 5: Dynamics of Dissolved Organic Phosphorus," In  Biogeochemistry of Marine Dissolved Organic Matter, 2nd Edition; Dennis A. Hansell and Craig A. Carlson (Eds.);  Academic Press (Elsevier Inc.): London, UK, 2015, p. 234–334 (ISBN: 978-0-12-405940-5).


"Total Phosphates" refers to the percentage of phosphate molecules in the sample, while "Total Phosphorus" denotes the percentage of phosphorus atoms in the sample, regardless of what molecules contain them.

Could you give an example of when a phosphorus atom would exist in biomass when it is not 'as phosphate'? In ATP, for example, phosphorus exists in the atom as tri-phosphate, and so is still as phosphate.

@Soof_fie- phosphonates, especially aminoethylphosphonate and its derivatives, are quite common in biology, though of course no where near as abundant as phosphate

@Soof_fie - example: https://www.lipidmaps.org/resources/lipidweb/lipidweb_html/lipids/complex/phophono/index.htm
